# How do you disable the touchscreen on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

How do you disable all touchscreen functionality in Windows 10? I searched through all the control panel settings but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Hit **Win+X** and select **Device Manager** from the menu.

Open the **Human Interface Devices** section.

Find the **HID-compliant touch screen** entry.

Right click on it and select **Disable Device**.